# Manually running cron from the server

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have a staging server begind basic auth and I'd like to run system cron instead of WordPress 'cron'.

I've placed the `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in my `wp-config.php`, and first I've added

```bash
*/5 * * * * curl -u user:pass https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

but then I thought to myself, why don't I just ping the file directly?

```bash
*/5 * * * * php /home/mysite_staging/www/example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

Is there a difference in doing this, besides not using curl to execute a request? Is executing a request a necessary step?

Comment: Ping what file? If you have a file in a theme or plugin that you want to hit directly then that file cannot use any WordPress functions or APIs.

Comment: `wp-cron.php` file. So a curl request towards the `wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` will also bootstrap the entire WP, but `php wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` won't and that's the problem (if my hunch is right)? I just need to trigger cron events.

Comment: `php` won't work because you need to send a POST request. Even if you didn't, loading the file would still bootstrap WordPress. It needs to to work properly. Otherwise what would you be running? The scheduled events are added by WordPress, themes, and plugins, so they obviously all need to be loaded.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized it depends on the `GET` parameter ‍♂️. The idea was to skip the basic auth and just try to trigger WP cron somehow without the actual request using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[WP CLI](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/cron/event/run/) to the rescue! Instead of using `php` and trying to figure out the rest, install it on the server and just have your cron execute

```
wp cron event run --due-now --path=/home/mysite_staging/www/example.com/
```

Comment: I thought about using wp cli to trigger my cron events. I did get some errors, but I'll see what I can do. Thanks!